# How to move CS-CART theme only from a server to another?

Tags: php, cpanel, cs-cart

My question is straightforward, how can I move a cs-cart theme only from a server to another without moving anything more than it?

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend you to 
1) Copy the theme files from you original store to the new store theme respository
The installed themes are located at design/themes, the themes repository is located at var/themes_repository.
So you need to do something like this in case the stores are on the same server

```
cp -R ./design/themes/MY_THEME ../new_store/var/themes_repository
```

In you case with different servers I would recommend you to backup you theme folder ./design/themes/MY_THEME and extract on the new server to the ./var/themes_repository folder.

After that you will find you theme in the "Browse all available themes" tab in the CS-Cart themes page.

2) Also you can find necessary to import the location for you store - it can be done easily using CS-Cart built-in Export/Import layouts feature. 
You can find it in Design -> Layouts under Gear button.
Here you can find more details http://docs.cs-cart.com/4.2.x/themes/layout.html